# Cannot open spark from cmd but running fine from Jupyter

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I just installed Spark in Windows. When I am running `pyspark` from jupyter its working fine but cannot open from `cmd` (though working directly from `bin` folder). I have checked the path but it's fine.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\VB>spark-shell
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\VB>pyspark
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\VB>sparkR
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

In Jupyter:

[image: Jupyter Notebook Screenshot]

Please tell where is the problem

Comment: You say you are working directly from bin folder - yet in your example you are trying those commands in your home directory. Could you clear that up please?

Comment: I mean when I open the spark bin folder and run the .cmd both by command and by double click. There must be some silly mistake from my end in setting the environment path but cannot discover it. Actually i am just learning Data-science and a newbie.

Comment: Also I think the problem wont hamper my using spark but just want to know the cause.

Comment: Can you please show us your JAVA_HOME and SPARK_HOME variables?